# Automatic columns

Tags: css

I have a long list of short items, such as below:

- Apples
- Oranges
- Banana
- USB stick
- ...

I would like this list to split into columns automatically to fill the width of the containing element, such that no item is broken onto two lines ("USB`⏎`stick" ), and the bullets line up nicely. Is this even possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. With [css columns](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/#the-number-and-width-of-columns), you can set either the column width or the number of columns. There's no 'auto detect width' option.

I usually go for width in `em` and let the number of columns depend on the client's browser window width.